# Cannot resolve symbol 'logger' on DuplicateKeyException

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, on-duplicate-key

In short: the object "logger" is not recognized unlike in many tutorials.

The problem on its own is not very serious and I can easily go around it. However it is very frustrating to see this "logger" stays in red in my intellIj editor. I am going through docs and blogs and I don't see what the problem is.

My snippet:

```
@Override
public void insertTicketStatut(TicketStatut pTicketStatut) {
    String vSQL = "INSERT INTO statut {id, libelle} VALUES {:id, :libelle}";

    BeanPropertySqlParameterSource vParams = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(pTicketStatut);
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate vJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(getDataSource());

    try {
        vJdbcTemplate.update(vSQL, vParams);
    } catch (DuplicateKeyException pE){
        logger.error("Le TicketStatut existe déjà ! id="+ pTicketStatut.getId(),pE);
    }
}
```

Hovering over logger shows "Cannot resolve symbol 'logger'
Thanks for your help.

Comment: it means you didn't declare a logger variable in that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logger needs to be either instantiated or better injected. It seems that you did not do that. When you use some kind of logging framework like log4j the initialisation would look like this:

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName());
```

When you show us the whole class we can see more details and can guess better.

An tutorial for log4j and spring can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging).

Answer (score 2):

Recommend using sl4j

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

Then instantiate:

```
//generic way to declare logger to be able to copy/paste to other classes
//without changing the class name
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
```

In dependency, include the binding for sl4j implementation ( can be log4j ).

Can refer here:

[logging-with-slf4j](https://dzone.com/articles/logging-with-slf4j)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I didn't managed properly my imports:

I added:

```
    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(TicketDaoImpl.class);
```

from

> org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

Stupid lack of attention.

I am having a look also at the doc from log4j/ sl4j on Baeldung. Thanks ^^